# AWS change region of static homepage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

For GDPR compliance, I need to change the location of the static homepage from US to Germany.

The infrastructure that was used (before I started) uses a S3 container which is addressed by a CloudFront distribution. The entries in Route53 points to the cloudfront distribution.

Initially, the S3 container with the name of the homepage domain was hosted in the US, therefore I created an intermediate container and afterwards the S3 container with the same name and the same content as before, however now hosted in Germany.

I also updated cloudfront to use the new S3 container, however according to the DNS lookup from [whatismyip.com](https://www.whatismyip.com/dns-lookup/), the homepage is still hosted in the US. I also invalidated the cloudfront cache for `/*` beforehand.

Any ideas what I might have overlooked? If it helps, I can share further information of my configuration.

Thank you!

Comment: Amazon CloudFront has edge locations all around the world. When the DNS name is resolved, it sends you to the closest location (or the one with the lowest latency). Thus, to _you_ it might look like it is coming from the US, but to somebody in Germany it would appear to be coming from Germany. Since you are using CloudFront, the actual location of the S3 bucket is somewhat irrelevant because people don't access it directly.

Comment: With what exactly do you attempt to comply?  Is it about where the static data is stored?

Comment: AFAIK, according to GDPR regulations, it is required to host a homepage in the EU. I thought this needs to be ensured by storing the data on a S3 bucket that is hosted in Europe - with my new understanding of CloudFront, this did not seem to have been necessary. Although I am not sure if this is sufficient to comply with GDPR regulations. Any hint on that would be highly appreciated. Thank you both for your comments.

Comment: You could probably claim that CloudFront is 'hosting' the home page in the EU. Do you have a reference to those GDPR rules?